# How to dump an active config from Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, configuration-files

I'm hoping someone knows to to dump the active SIP configuration from Asterisk. I'm 100% at fault for this, but I haven't backed up my Asterisk config files in a few months. This morning I tried to make a change to sip.conf, and wound up emptying the config file rather than saving my change. The system is still running, but the next reload/restart is going to disable the system completely.

Is there a way to pull a config from an active Asterisk instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way dump config.

But you can get passwords and some settings for sip using following commands

```
asterisk -r
sip show peers
sip show users
sip show user XXXX
sip show peer XXXX
```

Replace XXXX with user name you want to see more detailed.

If you used in your config type=friend, you will get both peer and user section with same name.